# Entity Framework Core : Access parent from child

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, relationship, ef-core-2.2

Might be a silly question but I'm a bit confused here.

I have a parent entity which contains a list of children.

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

EFcore will create a `ParentId` as a foreign key in the table `Child`.

Now, let's say I want to retrieve all the children that have a specific Parent, how should I do it ? The `ParentId` is not available in the `Child` object.

Therefore, I cannot do something like:

```
var result = model.Child.Where(child => child.ParentId == 3);
```

I could add the `ParentId` property to the child in the entity, but I really don't want this property to be assigned manually. And if I set it as readonly by specifying the getter only, the migration doesn't work anymore.

Comment: is there a reason you can't use parent itself to find the children.. meaning something along the lines of .. `model.parents.Single(p=> p ==3).Children` ?

Comment: No because I use the children ID to find the children. It's only afterwards that I have to check that the children does belong to the parent. Also, I don't want to query all the children, just one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EF Core allows you to access the associated [shadow property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties) in LINQ to Entities query using the [EF.Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.ef.property?view=efcore-2.1) method:

> Addresses a given property on an entity instance. This is useful when you want to reference a shadow state property in a LINQ query. Currently this method can only be used in LINQ queries and can not be used to access the value assigned to a property in other scenarios.

All you need to know is the name and the type - in your case they are "ParentId" and `int?` (optional):

```
var result = model.Child.Where(child => EF.Property<int?>(child, "ParentId") == 3);
```

Comment: You can also do `model.Child.Where(child => child.Parent.Id == 3)`, the generated sql will still use `ParentId`.

Comment: @jeuxjeux20 Sure it will, but *if there is* `Child.Parent` navigation property. The model in question has nether navigation nor explicit FK property, so the `EF.Property` is the only solution for such model type.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you have both the references (child-parent and parent-children) in the respective classes as provided in @ScotG answer.

However,since you dont want that, in EF using lazy loading you can do something like `model.Parents.Find(3).Children` since from the Parent class you have the references of its children.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // add these navigation properties to access the Parent
    public int ParentId {get; set; }
    public Parent Parent {get; set; }
}
```

https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/conventions/one-to-many-relationship

Comment: Why both ParentId and Parent ? Like mentioned above, I would like to avoid to be able to set those properties manually in the code